# Trends in Flash memory and SRAM for embedded (avr / msp microcontroller) systems

Tags: embedded, hardware, avr

I am wondering how the memory in deeply embedded systems such as avr/msp microcontroller (avr atmega128/TI msp430) would evolve. My hunch is that Flash memory is becoming smaller and cheaper at a much faster rate than SRAM.  I am looking for cost per byte and size per byte of Flash memory used in avr/msp and internal SRAM to backup that claim. I googled quite a bit but couldn't find clear answer yet. Any pointers or data would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: [FRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectric_RAM). SRAM takes fewer transistors to my knowledge then Flash, but I am sure someone will verify.

Comment: http://download.micron.com/pdf/presentations/events/flash_mem_summit_jcooke_inconvenient_truths_nand.pdf I personally ran into read disturb problems on a spi flash, turns out it was nand based.  its not that flash is cheaper than sram, it is that for a microcontroller application the flash to sram ratio is heavy on the flash side, turn the crank on the possibilities for clock rate, I/O pads, how much flash how much sram, peripherals and the market and you come up with the kinds of chips you see on the market, heavier on the flash than sram.

Comment: I am guessing that flash uses less power than sram too, another factor in that microcontroller options pool.

Answer (score 2):

An older chip, but see these die shots of the AT90S8515:

http://www.flylogic.net/blog/?p=24

The article states the flash as 8KB, SRAM 512B.

By eye, the RAM area highlighted is about 25% the size of the flash area, so you might get 2KB in the same area. Hence (in that chip on that process) flash seems about 4x more dense than SRAM.  And cost and area are very closely linked in silicon terms.

The reason there's more flash in a micro is not really related to cost though - you'll always get lots of flash relative to SRAM as that's where the application code lives!  The two types of memory have very different characteristics and hence functions within an embedded system.

Comment: @dwelch: Thanks dwelch and Martin for your answers/comments.
I understand Flash is used for storing programs and SRAM is used for data memory. I am developing a solution that offloads some of the data from SRAM to Flash intelligently and this makes me wonder whether such a solution would stand the test of time. Suppose tomorrow SRAM became cheaper and smaller, even though unlikely, my solution would become irrelevant. I am looking for the (past and present) cost/byte and size/byte of both sram and flash chips, so I could guess how it would evolve.